# How to list all row of a table and when join with another table is possible only the first row of it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm setting up an "order management" application which should provide a datalist listing up all my catalog item and show for each of them the "last order date". I also want the items not ordered yet to be reflecting without last order date.

I have tried this query without success

```sql
SELECT i.id, i.name, d.name 
FROM items i
JOIN LEFT orders o
ON i.id = o.items
```

I have these tables in my MySQL database:

**ITEMS**

```
ID|Name 
-----------
0 |Table
1 |Chair
2 |Screen
3 |Speaker
4 |Keyboard
5 |Laptop
6 |Mug
```

**ORDERS**

```
ID|ITEMS|DATE
-----------------
0 |  0  |20190122
1 |  0  |20181231
2 |  1  |20180601
3 |  3  |20180122
4 |  2  |20171231
5 |  4  |20180501
4 |  6  |20171115
5 |  3  |20180101
```

And would like the following output :

**LAST_ORDER_DATE**

```
ID|NAME    |DATE
--------------------
0 |Table   |20190122
1 |Chair   |20180601
2 |Screen  |20171231
3 |Speaker |20180122
4 |Keyboard|20180501
5 |Laptop  |
6 |Mug     |20171115
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use MAX() to get the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

seems you need  max date so you could use max( ) function and group by

```
select  i.id, i.name, max(o.date)
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN  orders o ON i.id = o.items 
group by i.id, i.name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also convert the existing string (if it is a char field) to date format like the following query if needed

```
select  i.id, i.name, max(str_to_date(date,'%Y%m%d'))
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN  orders o ON i.id = o.items 
group by i.id, i.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

change the table and column names as you have:

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    MAX(t2.pdate) AS last_order_date
FROM
    test t1
    LEFT JOIN test1 t2 ON t1.id = t2.items
GROUP BY
    t2.items,
    t1.name
ORDER BY
    last_order_date;
```

**Tables :**

[image]

[image]

**Output :**

[image]

if you are using string value in date then convert to date.